# Is it true for rvs $X,Y$ where $E[X]=E[Y]$ & $V[X] \geq V[Y],$ the Jensen gap of $X$ is larger or equal the Jensen gap of $Y?$

Tags: variance, probability-inequalities, convex

Is it true for rvs $X,Y$ where $E[X]=E[Y]$ and $V[X] \geq V[Y],$ the Jensen gap of $X$ is larger or equal the Jensen gap of $Y?$

It seems intuitive. I failed to prove it or find a reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Suppose $X$ has values $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $Y$ has values $\{-2,0,2\}$ both with mean zero (so $X$ puts less mass on zero in order to have larger variance). Suppose the function $f$ is constant on $[-1.5,1.5]$ and increases linearly outside that interval (eg $f(z)= \max\{0, |z|-1.5\}$)

$f$ is convex, but $f(E[X])=E[f(X)]=0$ and $f(E[Y])<E[f(Y)]$, so the Jensen's inequality gap is 0 for $X$ and non-zero for $Y$.

(The same can be done with a *strictly* convex function; it just takes making $f$ piecewise very slightly quadratic rather than piecewise linear).